# am I obliged to backshift if I believe but am not sure that the situation is still true

Tags: reported-speech

"please do not send the parcel until the record(vinyl) has been out"
reported speech

I told you not to send the parcel until the record had been out

This is the message I received, so could the buyer have written "has been " instead of "had been" because  he could think that the situation might still  be true (the record is not out) at the time he sent this message

Comment: By "out," do you mean "available for purchase"? Also, it's not clear in what circumstances you are replying. Are you replying to the person who gave you this instruction? What are you saying to him? Please try to give an idea of what the full exchange would look like.

Comment: i sold 2 records to the same guy but i did not have both of them: only one the other one was not out at the time , so I was waiting for it and the buyer told me to wait till i had both in stock